# Auto Delete Mongo Document if Email is Not Confirmed in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, nodemailer

I have a working user registration system in NodeJS using Express and Mongoose. At the moment when the user creates an account, a confirmation email will be sent to that email and when the link is clicked, it will confirm their account and let them set a password. Though I want to delete the entire mongo document if the user does not confirm their account within 60 minutes. What is the best method on going about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well `mongoose` is a `javascript` wrapper over `mongoDB` so you should just use regular `javascript` to do this.

I would take advantage of the `pre` hook:

https://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html#pre

I would set a timeout of 60 minutes and run a `delete` query to `mongoose` and set the timer id you get in response of the `setTimeout` function to the actual document that gets created.

I would then, in case of validation of the account, clear the timer and remove the entry in the new user's document.

In case nothing happens, the document gets programmatically deleted.

```
schema.pre("save", async function(next) {
  const id = setTimeout(function() {
    const document = await Model.findOne(/* use some unique value with this */);
    await document.remove() 
    }, 3600000);
  this.timerId = id;
  next();
}
```

Then in case of validation you run:

```
const document = await Model.findOne(/* find the document */);
clearTimeout(document.id);
```

This should be enough to handle the whole flow.

Please let me know if it's enough! :)

Comment: Seeing some code would be nice if it doesn't bother :)

Comment: @Nitecell Cool did you try it?

Answer (score 1):

Don't use setTimeout or remove method(remove is now deprecated) to do this with mongoose. If for some reason your server goes down you may lose the expiry. Another reason for this as well is you cannot horizontally scale with that solution. Also there is more efficient ways of going about this in my opinion.

There are three options to go about this:

1. **Utilize MongoDB TTL**
   What you should do is create a TTL Index with a partialFilterIndex and essentially delete documents based off of their expiry and make sure the filter doesn't delete verified accounts. This will let mongoDB do te work for you.
2. **Use a Message queue like rabbitMQ**
   For this solution use a message queue that sends timed messages. For example in rabbitmq you can set a message after a specific time. That will let your servers' recieve the message after the expiry is up and you can check if it's verified, if not delete the document.
3. **Cron Job to bulk delete**
   Another option is to have a cron job running at a set time (every day or week depending on your needs) and use a mongoose method that deletes documents that have passed their expiry and have not been confirmed.